# Keycloak Autenticator SPI to override redirect_uri

Tags: keycloak

Does Keycloak Authenticator SPI able to override the redirect_uri after successful login to desired url?
Right now after successful login user will be redirected to the url they requested before, In my organization we have a use case where a group of users (external user) can login to the application but only able to view specific frontend client.

We already add extra user attribute "eligibleApp" to the external user, and we will use this attribute to redirect to its url regardless of what the user requested before.
We also map "eligibleApp" attribute to the jwt token so that the frontend application can use this to redirect their eligible application.
We haven't found any documentation about how we suppose to do this in the Keycloak Authenticator SPI, we only able to add some logic to function `authenticate()` and `action()` describe in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#implementing-an-authenticator

Comment: Authenticators are for authentication only. You can't do anything if the authentication is successful, it pretty much redirects to the URI that you have configured.

Maybe you can create a new client and configure a new redirect URI so you have two groups separated that way.

Comment: @Sithira thank you for the response friend, but the client configuration setting only configuring the valid redirect url that is allowed not actively redirect to the url specified